# How to do nested navigation in react native expo

Tags: react-native

I am developing a react native application.

Here i am using this way to navigate between screens, navigatiion works OK. but when i press back button from the 3rd level screen, it comes to the 1st level screen instead of 2st level screen.

how do i fix this? please help me.

```
   const HomePageScreen = createStackNavigator({
      HomeLists: {
       screen: HomeScreen,
       navigationOptions: {
         header: null
       }
      },
      HotAdsLists: {
        screen: AdsDetailScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
           title: 'Hot Ads2',

        }
      },
      DetailsScreen: {
      screen: DetailsScreen,
      },
   });

    const SearchStack = createStackNavigator({
      Home:{
        screen:HomePageScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
          header: null
        }
     }
    },{
     initialRouteName: 'Home',
     headerMode: 'screen'
    });

    const DrawerNavigatorExample = createDrawerNavigator({
      SearchStack
    },{
        drawerType: 'slide',
        contentComponent: Page2ComponentExample,
        drawerBackgroundColor: '#4eb6ce'
    });
```

Comment: Are you changing your screens from the Drawer ?

Comment: @Vivek Yes ....

Comment: you can find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34496246/handling-back-button-in-react-native-navigator-on-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack is working properly
I done the stack manually and it works fine.